# Angular mat-select don't show option properly on mobile or low width devices

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I'm using mat-select in an angular project. When it comes to large screens, the options are shown properly but it is the opposite on mobile or low res screens. 
Actually, the options are shown but the text is missing. 
I've tried setting the max width of the mat-option with no success. 
When i select an option, it is selected and shown properly, but there is no way to know what option is selected. 
With images,
Expected behavior: 
[image]

Current behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the text with the answers is offscreen to the left. If you make the strings in the dropdown very long, you'll start to see them.

You need to change the following css properties:

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
    min-width: 200px !important; //or whatever width you want goes here
    .mat-select-panel {
        min-width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

The `!important` tags are to override the native material styles.

Comment: Oh, I set encapsulation: none in the component typescript file and now this works.